# Suspicious entry in task manager, "kerfisrof"

Tags: windows, windows-10

I've noticed that my computer has been starting slowly and being extremely laggy after startup. So, I opened task manager, and noticed a process called "Kerfisrof", taking 100% of the CPU.

The process has no RAM usage, no PID ("-"), is running on SYSTEM user, and has a description "Frestuð ferilsköll og forskriftir truflunarþjónstu".

Appearently, this is one of the very few system processes that have description in Icelandic, but the problem is...

not only it's written in the poetic/artistic dialect, but...

"Kerfisrof" means "open wound in the system"
"Frestuð ferilsköll og forskriftir truflunarþjónstu" means "postponed crashes of career and the programme of disruption service"

sounds suspicious enough, right?

The question, what is this?

Comment: Did you _Troubleshoot problems_ in `Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Network and Sharing Centre`?

Comment: With task manage open and on the process tab, click 'view" on the header and tick, "image path name", see if it shows a folder path to what has started that process Kerfisrof

Answer (score 0):

I dont speak Icelandic, but given its PID is not a number it sounds like your looking at [the "System Interrupts" process](https://superuser.com/questions/852656/what-is-the-system-interrupts-process-in-windows)? If so its a legit Microsoft process thats used as a virtual representation of your hardware. In English, System Interrupts is described as "Deferred procedure calls and interrupt service routines". This process basically represents the processor time spent dealing with the hardware itself.

If "Kerfisrof" is the System Interrupts process, 100% CPU usage is a symptom of some other problem, but implies you probably have some hardware or driver issue. Check your Event Logs and possibly enable Boot logging to get more clues.